# multi-dimension array problem in RGSS (RPG Maker XP)

Tags: ruby, rpg-maker-xp

This is my first day code script in RMXP. I read tutorials, ruby references, etc and I found myself stuck on a weird problem, here is the scenario:

1. I made a custom script to display layered images
2. Create the class, create an instance variable to hold the array, create a simple method to add an element into it, done
3. The draw method (skipped the rest of the code to this part):

> ```
>   def draw
>     image = []
>     index = 0
>     for i in 0..@components.size
>       if image.size > 0
>         index = image.size
>       end
>       image[index] = Sprite.new
>       image[index].bitmap = RPG::Cache.picture(@components[i][0] + '.png')
>       image[index].x = @x + @components[i][1]
>       image[index].y = @y + @components[i][2]
>       image[index].z = @z + @components[i][3]
>       @test =+ 1
>     end
>   end
> ```

1. Create an event that does these script

> ```
> > $layerz = Layerz.new $layerz.configuration[0] = ['root',0,0,1]
> > $layerz.configuration[1] = ['bark',0,10,2] 
> > $layerz.configuration[2] = ['branch',0,30,3]
> > $layerz.configuration[3] = ['leaves',0,60,4] $layerz.draw
> ```

1. Run, trigger the event and the result :

ERROR! **Undefined method`[]' for nil:NilClass** pointing at this line on draw method :

> image[index].bitmap = RPG::Cache.picture(@components[i][0] + '.png')

THEN, I changed the method like these just for testing:

```
def draw
    image = []
    index = 0
    for i in 0..@components.size
      if image.size > 0
        index = image.size
      end
      image[index] = Sprite.new
      image[index].bitmap = RPG::Cache.picture(@components[0][0] + '.png')
      image[index].x = @x + @components[0][1]
      image[index].y = @y + @components[0][2]
      image[index].z = @z + @components[0][3]
      @test =+ 1
    end
```

I changed the **@components[i][0]** to **@components[0][0]** and **IT WORKS**, but only the root as it not iterates to the next array index

Im stuck here, see :

```
> in single level array, @components[0] and @components[i] has no problem
> in multi-dimension array, @components[0][0] has no problem BUT
> in multi-dimension array, @components[i][0] produce the error as above
> mentioned.
```

any suggestion to fix the error ? Or did I wrote something wrong ?

Comment: Have you tried a [nested hash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720932/create-two-dimensional-arrays-and-access-sub-arrays-in-ruby) instead?

Comment: XP is old. It was old in 2003. Consider upgrading to a newer RPG Maker.

Comment: @Byte56 : For the last resort, I'll try hash or vector, so this is confirmed as array limitation in ruby ?

Comment: @ashes999, yes it is old, but I need XP for its styles (VX and VXAce has chibi-character style, I dont like it) And most custom script available in forum dedicated to XP

Comment: I'm not sure about "confirmed" but the nested hash does seem easier.

Comment: I used to agree with you, but then I tried VXAce, and I got used to it. Just try it.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after doing some reading, understanding ruby, I found the solution without changing the data type to hash/vector

```
  def draw
    image = []
    index = 0
    @components.each { |arr|
      if image.size > 0
        index = image.size
      end
      image[index] = Sprite.new
      image[index].bitmap = RPG::Cache.picture(arr[0] + '.png')
      image[index].x = @x + arr[1]
      image[index].y = @y + arr[2]
      image[index].z = @z + arr[3]
      @test =+ 1
    }
  end
```

**each** function is really convenient, I just learned that. Thanks the feedback guys.